# SpringApplication unrecognised

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have the following code:

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

But Eclipse is not able to recognise SpringApplication and is not able to import the library for it.

`build.gradle` contains:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

        compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    compile 'com.qas:proweb:1.0.0'

    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

Anything that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to update your dependencies? Or manually add the import and try to build it with gradle?

Comment: I did, but it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong dependency. Try to delete this one (not from build script dependencies, but from project's):

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE"
```

And add the

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.7.RELEASE")
```

Then just update you deps

Comment: I have posted the modified `build.gradle` as an answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

The build.gradle file was modified as follows, to make it work:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'

        compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
    compile 'com.qas:proweb:1.0.0'

    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion"

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.5.RELEASE"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```